# Why this if accepts all conditions, even ones it shouldn't?

Tags: c, if-statement

Afternoon, I have a question that asks me to check if multiple inputted lengths are smaller than an original base value (20x20x20) and tell case by case if they would fit inside of the base value or not, I tried it as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


int main(){
    char mala[3][3]={"20","20","20"};
    int n=0,k=2,j=0,i=0,u=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char caixa[3][3];
    char casos[2][6]={"good","bad"};
    char nmr[n][6];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%s %s %s",caixa[0],caixa[1],caixa[2]);
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            k=mala[j]-caixa[j];
            if(k<0){
                strcpy(nmr[i],casos[2]);
                break;
            }
            strcpy(nmr[i],casos[1]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        u=i+1;
        printf("Caso %d: %s\n",u,nmr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason all values enter the if, even for k>0, so any input gets "bad" as an output, can someone explain why?
Thank you.

Comment: `mala` is not containing numbers, it contains strings. So `k=mala[j]-caixa[j];` is quite meaningless (in fact its undefined behavior).

Comment: Just what do you think `mala[j]-caixa[j]` represents?

Comment: @EugeneSh.oh I understand now, what should I do then to store pure numbers?

Comment: @hmkla Use `int` instead of `char` and `20` instead of `"20"`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz OP would also have to fix `scanf` to read integers instead of strings.

Comment: In C, array indexes start at 0. Therefore `strcpy(nmr[i],casos[2]);` is an out of bounds access as `casos[2]` does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

`mala[j]-caixa[j]` is arithmetic on unrelated pointers. For pointers that don't point to the same object or objects in the same array, the only valid operations you can do are `==` and `!=`. You are causing undefined behavior here, and thus your output is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

`mala` and `caixa` are char arrays. While you can use this for 8-bit integers, the integer value of the ascii is not what the string reads as. "20" in asci has the integer values [50, 48, 0], '2' as an ascii character is 50, '0' is 48, and the null terminator is 0.